# How to set value to `Item` of struct using F#

Tags: struct, f#, set

How to set value to `Item` of struct? I have tried the following two types but both end up with the `value must be mutable` error.

```
module Test1 =
  [<Struct>]
  type Test (array: float []) =
    member o.Item
      with get i = array.[i]
      and set i value = array.[i] <- value

  let test = Test [|0.0|]
  test.[0] <- 4.0

module Test2 =

  [<Struct>]
  type Test =
    val mutable array: float []
    new (array: float []) = { array = array }
    member o.Item
      with get i = o.array.[i]
      and set i value = o.array.[i] <- value

  let test = Test [|0.0|]
  test.[0] <- 4.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to replace:

```
 let test = Test [|0.0|]
```

with:

```
 let mutable test = Test [|0.0|]
```